# Scheduled Task Not Creating Excel File

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I developed an application which grabs some data from our server, spits it out into an excel sheet, and emails that sheet to specific users. I needed this application to launch every 30 minutes so I setup a scheduled task on our server to run this application. What I can't figure out is this: The application runs (I can see that the data is being collected from our database (marked as hit in a [Processed] column)), but it will not create the excel file, and consequently does not send the email.

I need to figure out why so this process can work for me. A few things to note:
1.) I am an admin for this machine. (double checked my authorities)
2.) Excel IS installed on this machine.
3.) The scheduled task doesn't work, but if I manually run the program it executes perfectly.
4.) Proper versions of .Net are installed.
5.) Other scheduled task exist that do similar operations and have no issues.

The server is 2008 Enterprise.

Comment: a) What user account is the scheduled task running under? (Your account doesn't matter; it's the one configured for the scheduled task.) b) Where is it trying to write the .xls file?

Comment: @KenWhite It is running under my personal account. It's trying to write the the applications \bin file.

Comment: @KenWhite Also marked as 'Run with Highest Privileges'.

Comment: The "applications \bin file" isn't a directory location that I know anything about, I'm afraid. Is the application installed in the Program Files directory? Where **specifically** is the app trying to write the .xls file?

Comment: @KenWhite Exact file path: \\appne02\net\Projects\_In Production\Desktop Applications\Wisp\Wisp\bin

Comment: Are you certain that you have write access to that folder? And that the scheduled task is running under your specific credentials? (It has to be configured that way directly in the scheduled task; it doesn't just use your credentials because you're the one logged in when the task runs). Is that folder on the server where SQL Server itself is running? It's rare for the SQL Server account to have write access to an app's folder. (You mention SQL Server in your tags, but there's no indication of it in your question other than a column being updated by your app.)

Comment: any final solution about it?